# how to save json content from a web query

Tags: python, json, web, urllib2

I have this following code for querying and saving the json response. The query returns me a json output but when I save it with my code then I can no longer retain the json format.

```
file_out='C:\\Users\\ayush488\\Desktop\\annotation_for_new_dataset\\url'+str(cnt)+'.txt'
    cnt=cnt+1

    response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.diffbot.com/api/article?token='+token+'&url='+url).read()
    with open(file_out,'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response,outfile)
```

Can anyone tell how to save the json content properly?

Here is the sample of the output:

```
"{\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/open.blogs.nytimes.com\\/favicon.ico\",\"author\":
```

Comment: `outfile.write(response)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are double-encoding the JSON response.

You are receiving a *string* value, one that `json.loads()` could turn into Python objects. To save that response to a file, do not encode, do not decode, just save it straight to the file object. The most efficient way would be to use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj):

```
import shutil

response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.diffbot.com/api/article?token='+token+'&url='+url).read()
with open(file_out,'w') as outfile:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, outfile)
```

Comment: Why is copyfileobj more efficient than outfile.write(response)?

Comment: Because it'll stream the response in chunks if it is large.